# Moving dataframes between notebooks

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to move two dataframes from notebook1 to notebook2

I've tried using nbimporter:

```
import nbimporter
import notebook1 as nb1
nb1.df()
```

Which returns:

`AttributeError: module 'notebook1' has no attribute 'df'` (it does)

I also tried using `ipynb` but that didn't work either

I would just write it to a excel file and read it but the index gets messed up when reading it in the other notebook.

Comment: I think this post might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674086/import-data-frame-from-one-jupyter-notebook-file-to-another

Comment: Can use parquet for long-term storage and preserving datatypes https://stackoverflow.com/a/73500091/5957834

Answer (score 1):

You could use a magic (literally what it's called, not me being cute lol) command called `store`. It works like this:

In notebook A:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
%store df # Store the variable df in the IPython database
```

Then in another notebook B:

```
%store -r # This will load variables from the IPython database
df
```

An advantage of this approach is that you won't run into problems with datatypes changing or indexes getting messed up. This will work with variable types other than pandas dataframes too.

The official documentation displays some more features [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html#module-IPython.extensions.storemagic)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to save it as a `csv`:

```py
df.to_csv('example.csv')
```

And then while accessing it in another notebook simply use:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', index_col=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use pickle to save then load your dataframe
From the first notebook

```
df.to_pickle("./df.pkl")
```

then from the second notebook

```
df = pd.read_pickle("./df.pkl")
```